# Accessing collection from a relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I have 2 tables.

`DirtyEvent` model and `Event` model.

I am retrieving `DirtyEvent` with `Event` which works fine

In blade I have:

```
    @if (\Request::is('profile/event'))
      @foreach ($events as $event)
        @if (empty( $event->image ))
        <div class="card-header">
          <span class="card-title"><a href="{{ url('profile/event/details/' . $event->id) }}"> {{($event->title) }}</a></span>
        </div>
        @else
        <div class="card-image">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ $event->image }}"></img>
          <span class="card-title"><a href="{{ url('profile/event/details/' . $event->id) }}"> {{($event->title) }}</a></span>
        </div>
        @endif
        <div class="card-content">
          <p><strong>Starts: </strong>@php echo ($startdate) @endphp - {{$event->startime }}</p>
        <br>
        @if ($startdate != $enddate)
          <p><strong>Ends: </strong>@php echo ($enddate) @endphp - {{$event->endtime }}</p>
        <br>
        @endif
        <p><strong>Description:</strong></p>
        <br>
        <p>{{$event->description }}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="card-action">
          <a href="{{ url('profile/event/edit/' . $event->id) }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <form method="POST" action={{ url('events/delete/' . $event->id) }}>
            {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <button type="submit" class="delete" style="border:none;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
          </form>
        </div>
      @foreach ($events->publicevents as $eventss)
      {{dd($events)}}
      @endforeach
      @endforeach
```

However dd($events) gives me:

```
DirtyEvent Collection -> relations -> publicevents -> Event collection
```

But, It is saying that publicevents do not exist in current collection.

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $id = Auth::id();
    $events = DirtyEvent::where('user_id', $id)
        ->with('publicevents')
        ->get();
    return view('events.viewEvent', compact('events'));
}
```

**Model**

```
public function publicevents()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Event', 'event_id');
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess not all dirty event objects have events. So check this first with `empty()` or `isEmpty()` or `count()`:

```
@if (!empty($event->publicevents))
    @foreach ($event->publicevents as $eventss)
        {{ $eventss->id }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

**Update**

It should be `$event->publicevents`, not `$events->publicevetns`.

Comment: the problem is I have one dirty event object and I know it has events so why can't I access them when I do see them in dd

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas thanks. The collection looks fine. If you use something like `{{ $eventss->id }}` inside foreach loop, what exactly error do you get?

Comment: Property [publicevents] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas thanks. The error is in foreach loop. It should be `$event->publicevents`

Comment: that's right, so embarassed I haven't noticed that -.- Friday kicks in, thanks